# SQL-ASCII encoding in database throws Error: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument

Tags: php, sql, encoding, utf-8, laravel-4

I have an old Postgresql database with `SQL-ASCII` encoding..

In Laravel, I tried to query records containing the characters `Ñ` and `ñ` but unfortunately, it throws the error `json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument`.

How do I solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: It cannot be ASCII. [ASCII cannot represent neither `Ñ` nor `ñ`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters). Furthermore, ASCII is just a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: I mean in the database, the Ñ character is represented by �. When I try to json_encode, it throws the error above. What should I do?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to store Spanish characters in ASCII. It's simply not possible, just like you cannot have an animated JPEG. Can't you just switch everything to UTF-8?

Comment: @Melvin - I'm experiencing the exact same problem with a MS SQL Server database encoded in collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @jjwdesign Yah.. I used this: `json_encode(utf_encode($var));`

Comment: @Melvin - Thank you! utf_encode() seems to work properly. These multi-byte character set conversions can be tricky.